# Calculating percentage and keeping names

Tags: r

I have the following DF named totals.

```
  Group    Year_2016  Year_2017  Year_2018
    A         342         2342      234
    B         231         2357      6867
    c         67          9796      75474
```

In the following code, I can calculate the correct percentage, but it does not keep the group column.

```
percentage = sapply(names(totals)[-1], function(x) {
Year[paste0(x, "_pct")] <<- totals[x] / sum(totals[x]})
```

I would like a percentage by group. Happy for it to be either additional columns or new DF.

I have hundreds of more rows and columns.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do `DF[paste0(names(DF)[-1], "_pct")] <- DF[-1]/rowSums(DF[-1])`  or it could be `DF %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate_at(-1, list(perc = ~ ./sum(.)))`

Comment: If you need more help, CISCO, please consider making this question a little more consistent (and reproducible). For instance, your code has mis-matched parens and you reference `Year` as a variable (vice `"Year"` as part of the columns' names?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can divide the columns by the `colSums` of the numeric columns

```
DF[paste0(names(DF)[-1], "_pct")] <- DF[-1]/colSums(DF[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question seems to be taking each column and dividing it by the sum of that column so we do that here. On the other hand the description says you want to do it by group which I assume means to take each row and divide by the sum of that row.  If you want this latter calculation then replace 2 with 1 in (1).  If you want each number as a fraction of the sum of all the numbers in the table then omit the second argument of `prop.table` or use NULL for that argument.

Also the calculation shown in the question calculates fractions, not percentages, so we do that here; however, the description says percentages.  If you want percentages multiply the third argument of `replace` by 100.

The columns names can be modified using

```
names(X) <- sub("Year", "pct", names(X))
```

where X is the result calculated below.

Except for (4) these use no packages.  (1) seems the most flexible as it is easy to adapt it to rows or columns.

**1)** Use `prop.table`.  This gives each number as a fraction of its column total.  Replace 2 with 1 to get each number as a fraction of its row total.

```
replace(totals, -1, prop.table(as.matrix(totals[-1]), 2))
```

giving:

```
  Group Year_2016 Year_2017   Year_2018
1     A 0.5343750 0.1615730 0.002833787
2     B 0.3609375 0.1626078 0.083160763
3     C 0.1046875 0.6758192 0.914005450
```

**2)** Another possibility is `sweep`:

```
replace(totals, -1, sweep(totals[-1], 2, colSums(totals[-1]), "/"))
```

**3)** or `scale`

```
replace(totals, -1, scale(totals[-1], FALSE, colSums(totals[-1])))
```

**4)** or use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
totals %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, prop.table)
```